# bayesian probability calculation

Tags: probability

a man has the probability of 0.9 to go out for a drink, and if he went out , he will usually go to one of the 3 bars he like

police searched 2 bars of the three, didn't find the man there

what's the probability that the man is drinking at the 3rd bar ?

my calculation:

- without the police searching the bar, the man at the 3rd bar with probability of 10/27
- with the police searched two bars, the man at the 3rd bar is probability of 90%

is this right? what's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the man picks one of the three bars to go to completely at random with equal probability (i.e. 1/3 chance each). That means that there is a $0.9 \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{3}{10}$ chance that he is at bar A. Similarly, there is a $\frac{3}{10}$ chance he is at bar B, and $\frac{3}{10}$ chance he is at bar C, and a $\frac{1}{10}$ chance that he is not at any of those bars.

Let's assume without loss of generality that the cops searched bars A and B and couldn't find the man. We found earlier that the probability he is at bar C is $\frac{3}{10}$ and that the probability that he is not there is $\frac{1}{10}$. So we find the probability that we need by (let's assume he stays home when he doesn't go out to drink):

$$\frac{(\text{the probability for the specific outcome we want})}{(\text{the sum of probabilities for each possible outcome})} = \frac{(\text{man @ bar C})}{(\text{man @ bar C}) + (\text{man @ home})}$$

$$= \frac{\frac{3}{10}}{\frac{3}{10}+\frac{1}{10}} = \frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: what is the problem with this thinking: now that the two bars are cleared, if the man wants to go out, he has to be in bar C,hence 90%

Comment: The probability that the man goes out is different from the probability that the man goes to bar C. More specifically, $(\text{man goes to bar}) = (\text{man goes to bar A}) + (\text{man goes to bar B}) + (\text{man goes to bar C})$. Your reasoning assumes that, if the man wanted to go out, he would only have gone to bar C, which goes against the statement of the problem (or, at least, the implied part of it).